# How do I make the camera move towards, then disappear into a hole in the ground that I motion-tracked into a video?

Tags: camera

I want to shoot some video of a road and some buildings and then use Blender's motion tracking to put a hole in the road. The hole will have a 'lid' and its top will match the road texture exactly so that it's hidden. I'll then make the lid revolve 180° to reveal the hole in the ground.
After I make the motion tracking bit (which I'm fine with) and I've got the ground to open up, I then want it to appear as if the camera is moving towards, then disappearing down, the hole. I'll then transition by means of a few black frames and some fades into a separate tunnel animation that I've already made.
Does anyone know how I might get the camera to do this?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Position your camera start, make a keyframe, position it where you want it to end, repeat. Then refine the transition. If the camera is stuck by your tracker, create a new one, copy its transforms, make it the active camera on frame x (last frame of your track I presume) and continue from there.

Comment: What have you tried so far that is not working?

Comment: If you are going to shoot the video, then just set a mark on the ground and execute the camera move as if the hole was there. Then create the hole and the lid in 3D.

Comment: Thank you both Frederik and susu.